# Transfer .com domain to GoDaddy - websites running on same domain - 3 weeks left until expiration, 2 days left web hosting

Tags: web-hosting, domain-registration, godaddy, domain-registrar

Our company purchased this `abc.com` domain from a local registrar.
The domain will expire in about 3 weeks.
We have our main websites running on this abc.com domain and they cannot be down for too long.
The web hosting service will end in 2 days.
Our websites are already hosted and they are up and running on Amazon EC2.

We would like to transfer the domain to GoDaddy now or as soon as possible.
(since we have many other domains there and we belive GoDaddy will be better in long-term considering the prices and the features it offers)

There are many questions on the decision to transfer the domain to GoDaddy:

**1) Cost and time required to move out of our local registrar?**

- This is currently unknown as I'm still trying to retrieve the agreement we have with them

**2) How does the 3 week time left until expiration of the domain matters here?**

- Should we wait until the domain expires and then purchase in through GoDaddy? How long would such process take as I suppose our websites will be down during that time? Any other drawbacks?

**3) What can I do to ensure our websites will continue functioning regardless of the domain transfer process?**

- It seems the actual registrar here is `enom.com` and the local registrar here just partners with it

  - I suppose I should then park the `abc.com` domain with `enom.com` and make changes to DNS settings so that our websites can continue to be hosted on EC2 as normal.
- How long does it normally take the domain to be transferred to GoDaddy completely?
- Is it even possible at all to keep our websites are up and running during the whole domain transfer process?

Apologies that I'm throwing many questions at the same time here.
It's rather last minutes and I suddenly realised there are too many unknown risks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transfer your domain from your current registrar to GoDaddy should be $7.99* More on that here http://www.godaddy.com/domains/domain-transfer.aspx

Do not wait for the domain to expire, it'll then go into redemption, deleting and maybe some other statuses.

Go to the GoDaddy page I linked to and begin your transfer now. You can even call them with questions `Call Transfer Concierge® anytime at 1-480-505-8866`. When you transfer you get 1 free year with GoDaddy so it'll renew with them. They are reputable and have great support. Transfers take 5-7 days maybe sooner

> "NOTE: For most domain name extensions, a transfer between registrars
>   takes five to  seven days from the time you authorize it"

Downtime i'm not sure of, you'll have to ask GoDaddy about that. You should be able to monitor the transfer pretty easily with GoDaddy and as soon as you have the domain update your name servers in GoDaddy to Amazon

Answer (score 0):

The domain registration process does not in itself cause any downtime. As long as the new record that GoDaddy registers declares the same nameservers as your current record, that transition is completely transparent.

Once the registration is transferred you can switch name servers to whomever will be providing your DNS resolution, just make sure the records for the domain are entered in the new servers before making the switch and again, the transition will be completely seamless for end users.

Making the change as described requires 0 downtime.

Switching web hosting services is a bit more involved and the amount of downtime will depend largely on the type of application that is being hosted and the architecture of web site software.

If you can get the site running in parallel on both the current and future servers then you can make this a zero downtime switchover as well with a simple A record change on you nameserver.